# JavaScript H2 color not changing when using Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an assignment to change all h2s on a given page using only JavaScript on the console**(developer tools)**. I have input the below code multiple times, however the console just returns the string "b;ue" rather than actually changing the element. If I use jquery it works fine, but unfortunately the assignment is for plain javascript. Could someone help point out the mistake? Is it because I'm running it on dev tools?

```
document.querySelector("h2").style.color="blue";
```

returns the string "blue" rather than changing the color

```
document.querySelectorAll("h2").style.color="blue"; //returns cannot read "color"?

$('H2').css('color', 'blue' );  //this runs fine on the dev tools but the assignment is for plain javascript.
```

Comment: the first should work fine but will only color the first h2 blue. To do them all, try `document.querySelectorAll("h2").forEach(element => element.style.color="blue")`

Comment: 'returns the string "blue"'. That's not relevant to the question itself, but I feel it makes sense to explain: every assignment in Javascript returns the assigned value. `a = 3` will return 3, for example.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your H2 contain anything other than just text? Like a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("h2").forEach(el => el.style.color = "blue"));
```

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will give you a NodeList on which you can than perform a [forEach(el)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) where `el` is every Element in the iteration.

Comment: it's an assignment, they need figure it out themselves not others give them actual answer...

Answer (score 1):

The function `document.querySelector` only returns the first element that satisfies the given selector. So you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all of the elements, but this function returns a `NodeList` so you need to loop through each element and change its color:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach(element => element.style.color='blue');
```